# Find TabStrip index

Tags: kendo-ui

Is it possible to find the index of a tab in a KendoUI TabStrip? I need to find the index (number) of the tab that I select and I know that `select()` returns me current tab but I don' t know how to convert this to the number.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
$("#tabstrip").data("kendoTabStrip").select().index();
```

Answer (score 7):

```
    function select(e) {
        var x = e.item;
        var index= $(e.item).index();
        $(".tabindex").val(index);
    }
```

as nemesv said in https://stackoverflow.com/a/15646629/2127493