# Kendo TabStrip: Getting the Selected Index on the Selected event (MVC 4)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-ui

My TabStrip is as follows:

```
        @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
              .Name("tabApplications")
              .Items(items =>
                  {
                      items.Add().Text("Online").Selected(true);
                      items.Add().Text("Trading");
                  })
              .Animation(false)
              .Events(e=>e.Select("tabstrip_select"))
              )
```

In Javascript I get theSelected Item:

```
     function tabstrip_select(e) {
         var x = e.item;
     }
```

**Question**: How do I get the Selected Index (ie "1") from this function. I looked over the Item object but didn't see anything obvious.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get the currently selected index with calling `index()` on the `$(e.item)`

```
function tabstrip_select(e) {
    var x = e.item;
    var selectedIndex = $(e.item).index();
}
```

Demo using [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SLs7J/).

Comment: another solution for when you are not in `tabstrip_select(e)` event: [`Find TabStrip index`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13606544/1997229)